# Why does sed only replace the first character?

Tags: sed

```
$ echo lcdefghijklmnopqrstblvcxyz | tr [a-i] [1-9] | sed 's/j/10/' | sed 's/k/11/' | sed 's/l/12/' | sed 's/m/13/' | sed 's/n/14/' | sed 's/o/15/' | sed 's/p/16/' | sed 's/q/17/' | sed 's/r/18/' | sed 's/s/19/' | sed 's/t/20/' | sed 's/u/21/' | sed 's/v/22/' | sed 's/w/23/' | sed 's/x/24/' | sed 's/y/25/' | sed 's/z/26/'
1234567891011l13141516171819202l223242526
```

The long command is intended to replace a..z with 1..26. Notice there are 3 "l" characters in the echoed string. Why is the first one correctly converted to "12" yet the other two (results 11l13 and 202l223) aren't?

I tried this on both my Windows 7 PC running Cygwin (bash 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)) and on my MacBook Pro running Terminal (bash 3.2) and got the same results.  I expected the result to be 1..26 concatenated.  This is part of a bigger problem that I reduced to this test case.

Comment: You don't need to run a separate `sed` command for each substitution. `sed -e 's/j/10/' -e 's/k/11/' -e 's/l/12/'`

Comment: And `sed` has a `y` command that's like `tr`.

Comment: You should probably replace `a..i` with `01..09`. Otherwise, when you have `123` in the result, you don't know if it came from `abc`, `aw`, or `lc`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `g` flag for the substitution to be repeated:

```
$ echo lll | sed 's/l/12/'
12ll
$ echo lll | sed 's/l/12/'g
121212
```

Without the `g` flag, `s` replaces the first instance, as documented in `man sed`.

Also, you can put all of those commands in a single invocation of sed. You don't need all those pipes:

```
sed 's/j/10/g;s/k/11/g;s/l/12/g...'
```

Comment: Thanks much -- missing that sed does 1 replace, and the g flag to change that, was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Multiple sed commands (with `g` switch)

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could try something like:

```
c=1 o=
for i in {a..z};do
    o+="s/$i/$((c++))/g;"
  done
sed -e "$o" <<<'lcdefghijklmnopqrstblvcxyz'
1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526
```

or

```
fold -s <<< ${o//;/; }
s/a/1/g; s/b/2/g; s/c/3/g; s/d/4/g; s/e/5/g; s/f/6/g; s/g/7/g; s/h/8/g; 
s/i/9/g; s/j/10/g; s/k/11/g; s/l/12/g; s/m/13/g; s/n/14/g; s/o/15/g; s/p/16/g; 
s/q/17/g; s/r/18/g; s/s/19/g; s/t/20/g; s/u/21/g; s/v/22/g; s/w/23/g; s/x/24/g; 
s/y/25/g; s/z/26/g;
```

then

```
sed -e '
  s/a/1/g; s/b/2/g; s/c/3/g; s/d/4/g; s/e/5/g; s/f/6/g; s/g/7/g; s/h/8/g;
  s/i/9/g; s/j/10/g; s/k/11/g; s/l/12/g; s/m/13/g; s/n/14/g; s/o/15/g; s/p/16/g;
  s/q/17/g; s/r/18/g; s/s/19/g; s/t/20/g; s/u/21/g; s/v/22/g; s/w/23/g; s/x/24/g;
  s/y/25/g; s/z/26/g;
' <<<'lcdefghijklmnopqrstblvcxyz'
1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{x;s/^/a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10k11l12m13n14o15p16q17r18s19t20u21v22w23x24y25z26/;x};G;:a;s/([a-z])(.*\n.*\1([0-9]+))/\3\2/;ta;P;d' file
```

This uses a [lookup table](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/tutorials/lookup_tables.txt) to translate the required strings.

Comment: nice..............always like your sed answers..even went to the extreme of memorizing one when i now started learning sed

Comment: @repzero thanks, but I only [`stand on the shoulders....`](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/)